# Парсинг pdf, постраничное разделение pdf

Tags: c#, парсер, itextsharp, pdfsharp

Для парсинга и разделения pdf файла использую две библиотеки. Никак не могу найти, как pdfshar парсит данные, а itextsharp позволяет разделить один 150 страничный pdf на 150 одностраничных pdf. Данный код работает верно, все выполняет, есть необходимость использования одной библиотеки. Подскажите, есть ли возможность привести все к одной библиотеке ?

```
  private async Task  ExchangeBillsPDFAsync(string path)
     
        {
            
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
            File.Copy(path, Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename), true);

            string resultPdfText = "";

            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();

            PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(filename, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfr = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(filename);

            Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
            Document.Compress = true;
            doc.Open();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfr.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                resultPdfText += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfr, i);
            }

            int j = 0;
            int chet = 0;
            int arhShet = 1;
            string[] sourceText = resultPdfText.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            for (int i = 0; i < sourceText.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (sourceText[i].Contains("ИЗВЕЩЕНИЕ"))
                {
                    i += 4;
                    string dateStr = sourceText[i].Substring(sourceText[i].IndexOf("ПЕРИОД") + 7);

                    DateTime date = default;
                    date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);

                    i++;
                    string ls = sourceText[i].Trim();
                    // ls = ls.Substring(sourceText[i].Length - 10);

                    PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();

                    outputDocument.Version = inputDocument.Version;

                    outputDocument.Info.Title = String.Format("Page {0} of {1}", j + 1, inputDocument.Info.Title);
                    outputDocument.Info.Creator = inputDocument.Info.Creator;

                    outputDocument.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[j]);
                    string pdfName = String.Format("Bills_keyField_{0}{1}.pdf", ls, date.ToString("Myyyy"));
                    outputDocument.Save(pdfName);
                    zip.AddFile(pdfName);

                }
            
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Этот код работает как надо? Если да, укажите это явно в посте.

Comment: да, он работает хорошо